# AWS elasticbeanstalk hooks: postdeploy works, predeploy doesn't

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using an ebs app on linux 2 platforms, and I need to clone a directory during deployment to get configfiles for my app.
I did a predeploy hook so that the files are there when the app starts after deployment: /.platform/hooks/predeploy/01_import

After deployment in a predeploy hook, the files are not there.
When I run the exact same script in a postdeploy hook, the files are there.

So the command works, I see the predeploy hook is running (I see the echo text in the log), but the files are not present. Anyone knows why?

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /var/app/current/config
echo Adding github in known hosts
ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> /home/webapp/.ssh/known_hosts
echo Done Adding github in known hosts
echo deleting old flows
echo cloning 
git -c core.sshCommand="ssh -i /etc/pki/tls/certs/githubKey" clone -b dev --single-branch <mygithub> /var/app/current/config
echo done cloning
```

Answer (score 0):

In predeploy stage, the new code is deployed to `/var/app/staging`, not `/var/app/current`.

`/var/app/current` is actually overwritten by staging if the new staging deployment is successful.

So in predeploy, I've cloned to staging instead, and it works.

This is not well documented in AWS docs; [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/things-to-keep-in-mind-while-deploying-to-elastic-beanstalk-b5742a7561a) helped me.